# No more, the house is full!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme

Everybody was looking down when the guests arrived
They came in the hall as they were contrived

First was heard a knock at the door, but luckily
The fellow had also brought the key

Then entered a brace of fowls, straight out of water
Followed by... Wait, was that the long-legged sister?

The next ones went to the corners and were very happy
When the egg and sausage was announced along a cup of tea

Did I mention it was the two fat ladies? Not being mean,
But they didn't look like the next guest, a dancing queen

And here came another, almost there
Almost three dozen, they were

"No more, the house is full!" shouted a man suddenly
Then no more entered, as the crowd turned bitter, sadly.

**What has just happened?**

Comment: **What has just happened?** Is the answer a phenomena here? Or is it a scenario which is defining something? e.g. a card/board game? You can chose not to answer if its too revealing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What has just happened is

> a game of (British, 90-ball) bingo.

The point here is that there are

> silly names for many of the numbers that a bingo caller will use. (Perhaps they originated as ambiguity-preventers. I think now they're mostly for tradition.)

Specifically, and in order of appearance, we have:

> 4: "Number four, knock at the door"
>  21: "Key of the door"
>  22: "Two little ducks"
>  11: "Legs eleven" (the long-legged sister)
>  54: "Egg and sausage"
>  3: "Number three, cup of tea"
>  88: "Two fat ladies"
>  17: "Dancing queen"
>  89: "Almost there"
>  36: "Three dozen"

Also,

> "*Everybody was looking down when the guests arrived*" referst to the fact that the Bingo caller calls "Eyes Down" at the start of a game.
>  "*They came in the hall as they were contrived*": the numbers enter the hall by the bingo machine.
>  The reference to corners is a sub-game in bingo where you get a prize for all four corners of your card marked off.

... at which point

> someone, having all the numbers they needed, shouted "Full House!" and the game was over.

Comment: Who else than you to answer this? Bingo!